# optimizing CSS selectors. Is `*+p` less costy than `p+*`

Tags: css, optimization

According to what I know about browsers' algorithm of CSS processing, selector `*+p` has less perfomance impact than `p+*`, doesn't it?

So, in the `p+*` browser scans through all elements on the page, and those that follow `p` are applied a corresponding rule.
In the `*+p` firstly it looks only for `p`, but does it stop the search immediateliy after finding some element before `p`, thus making less "search iterations"? Or `*` still scans here everything.

Also, which tools can show CSS loading time and other 'heavyweight' information. Found only those that search for unused or excess rules and compress the CSS for getting less size.

In context - I need to apply top-margin to any element that follows `p` (except `p+p`), the content is generated dynamically.
Having read that old browsers suffer much of universal selector, this very question had arised.

Comment: They are totally different selectors which have different meanings and usages, how can we compare between them?

Comment: Have you actually experienced any performance issues with CSS?

Comment: Found some css selectors perfomance [comparison](http://realityonweb.com/cascading-style-sheet-css/performance-improvement-by-writing-efficient-css-selector/) so got interested.  


Issue? - Not yet  - didn't have an opportunity to make appropriate tests with considerable amount of data on old clients. But having read about [their behavior](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/18/simplifying-css-selectors/) thought it'd be nice to know beforehand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just adding bottom margin to all p elements, wouldn't that have the same result? You can then add a rule for `p+p` with negative top margin to counteract the effect, e.g.:

```
p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

p + p {
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: As far as performance goes- this is probably the solution I'd opt for

Comment: really it solves this very problem, making unnecessary the main question. simple and clear

Comment: @bo. remember in the future to think about what element exactly you want to apply styles to :) Saying "every element below a `p` needs top margin" says a lot more about that `p` than about `every element`, so that's what you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to apply top-margin to any element that follows p (except p+p)

[**What about:**](http://jsfiddle.net/SjFaW/)

```
p + :not(p) {
    background:red;
}
```

As far as performance/efficiency, look at either the [Page Speed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) (FF) or [Speed Tracer](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ognampngfcbddbfemdapefohjiobgbdl) (Chrome)  browser extensions, both of which will help you analyse/identify problem CSS.

Comment: i thought of `:not`, but then also about old IEs, that still need their own treatment. Links look like what i've looked for.